# fingerprint-gui stucks on first repeat with errcode -22

Tags: fingerprint-reader

my fresh installed fingerprint-gui stucks when I try to register my fingers. The first scan gives a green tick, but when the program asks me to repeat the step the scanner wont scan it. Normally the scanner blinks green when reading, but not after the first swipe... The used scanner is from a Thinkpad T440,

```
ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
```

the Ubuntu Version is 15.10 and the system is up to date. Here is a detailed erorr Log:

```
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Started.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Proprietary lib "libbsapi.so.4.3" not found in library path.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Libfprint initialized.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Devices initialized.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Intel Corp./unknown device.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Linux Foundation/2.0 root hub.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Linux Foundation/3.0 root hub.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Lite-On Technology Corp./unknown device.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Intel Corp./unknown device.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Validity Sensors, Inc./unknown device.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Found USB device: Linux Foundation/2.0 root hub.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: initializing libfprint device (vend/prod) 0x138a/0x17, driver: vfs5011
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Added vfs5011.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Current device set to 0 -- vfs5011.
Jan 13 13:19:14 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Current device set to 0 -- vfs5011.
Jan 13 13:19:19 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Need 1 stages.
Jan 13 13:19:19 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Please Swipe Your Right Index.
Jan 13 13:19:19 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Swipe finger at vfs5011.
Jan 13 13:19:19 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Thread started.
Jan 13 13:19:19 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Starting acquire.
Jan 13 13:19:20 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Need 1 stages.
Jan 13 13:19:20 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire stage 0 waiting...
Jan 13 13:19:22 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire: have image.
Jan 13 13:19:22 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire result 100.
Jan 13 13:19:22 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: FP_ENROLL_RETRY.
Jan 13 13:19:22 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire stage 0 try again...
Jan 13 13:19:22 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire stage 0 waiting...
Jan 13 13:19:23 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire failed with error -22.
Jan 13 13:19:23 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire stage 0 waiting...
Jan 13 13:19:25 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire failed with error -22.
Jan 13 13:19:25 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire stage 0 waiting...
Jan 13 13:19:27 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire failed with error -22.
Jan 13 13:19:27 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Acquire stage 0 waiting...
Jan 13 13:19:27 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Stopping device...
Jan 13 13:19:27 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: FP_DEV_STOP.
Jan 13 13:19:28 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: FP_ASYNC_ENROLL_STOP.
Jan 13 13:19:29 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: FP_DEV_CLOSE.
Jan 13 13:19:30 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Stopped.
Jan 13 13:19:30 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: qApp exit.
Jan 13 13:19:30 Wubu fingerprint-gui[3224]: Devices released.
```

Where is the problem, or more specific what means error -22?
I haven't found any error->meaning list for fingerprint-gui...

The rest of the progam seems to work, the fingerprinter always blinks when auth is needed and only shows the error that it was unable to open the folder with the stored fprints (because there is no such folder since no finger was stored sucessfully...)

```
ingerprint-helper[3182]: Could not open /var/lib/fingerprint-gui/wucke/vfs5011/
```

So, thanks for any tips, suggestions or advices...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try Fprint?
https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint

I have same problem before when trying fingerprint-gui. 
Now I use Fprint and it works